# How do I use vue-datetime with timezones?

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I am using this [component](https://github.com/mariomka/vue-datetime) called vue-datetime and I am hoping someone has used the same use case as me.

I am trying to put a max-date based on any timezone a user's "assets" are in. I am using moment to get timezone dates.

```
<datetime
    v-model="date"
    zone="Asia/Tokyo"
    value-zone="Asia/Tokyo"
    :max-datetime="dateNow">
</datetime>
```

I am passing date and dateNow as

```
moment().tz('Asia/Tokyo').format()
```

which is as ISO 8601 string and these dates are right (it returns the local time in Tokyo). However, when I open the day picker, May 25 is disabled even though it is currently May 25 2:45 am in Tokyo.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default local zone for the country/city you want

Install luxon if not installed:

```
npm install --save luxon
```

Then

```
import moment from 'moment';
import { Settings } from 'luxon'
...
//set to display dates for English language
Settings.defaultLocale = 'en'
```

[image: image with the setting used]

Comment: moment().tz()
I think there is no such method

Answer (score 0):

`.tz()` is only available if you also install the `moment-timezone` package.

Example using npm (for others, see https://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```sh
npm install moment-timezone --save
```

Initialization example:

```js
import VueMoment from "vue-moment";
import moment from "moment-timezone";

moment.tz.guess();
Vue.use(VueMoment, { moment });
```

Documentation: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/